# What is the benefit of media query in an <a> tag ? how does it work?

Tags: html, media-queries

I have this simple HTML5 page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>trial</title>
    </head>
<body>

    <p>
    <a href="500.jpg" media="screen and (max-width:500px)">here is a link</a>
    <a href="1000.jpg" media="screen and (max-width:1000px)">here is a link</a>
    <a href="1920.jpg" media="screen and (max-width:1920px)">here is a link</a>
    </p>

</body>
</html>
```

When I open it in the browser it shows 3 links pointing to 3 images. The question is: I expected the media query to hide 2 of them because my screen resolution is 1920 by 1080. So if not what is the benefit of using media query in `<a>` tags as described in http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_media.asp

Comment: Neither the [WHATWG HTML Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-a-element), [W3C HTML5 Standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element), nor the [W3C HTML 5.1 Standard (Draft)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) indicate `media` as an allowed attribute of the `a` element...

Comment: is this http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_media.asp wrong ?

Comment: @docesam - Yes, but really just out of date. The HTML5 draft spec dropped the `media` attribute from the `a` element in June/July 2013, probably because no user agents were using it for anything.

Answer (score 1):

> This attribute specifies the media which the linked resource applies
>   to. Its value must be a media query. This attribute is mainly useful
>   when linking to external stylesheets by allowing the user agent to
>   pick the best adapted one for the device it runs on.

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

From the code in question, all the anchor tags will appear anyways, however if you use media query for CSS, then browser will apply that CSS only based on device.

Comment: so if adding a media query in an <a> tag does noting why was it mentioned in http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_media.asp ?